# Form validation error when using ion-scroll tag

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an Ionic app and I'm having some issues with form validation when I use **< ion-scroll>** tag. This is my form:

```
<form ng-show="!success" name="form" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="register()" show-validation>
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Nome"
                   ng-model="registerAccount.firstName" ng-minlength=1 ng-maxlength=50 required maxlength="50">
        </label>
        <div ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$invalid" class="padding-top padding-left assertive">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required">
                some message
            </p>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Senha"
                   ng-model="registerAccount.password" ng-minlength=5 ng-maxlength=50 required>
        </label>
        <div ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$invalid" class="padding-top padding-left assertive">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="form.password.$error.required">
                some message
            </p>
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Repita a senha"
                   ng-model="confirmPassword" ng-minlength=5 ng-maxlength=50 required>
        </label>
        <div ng-show="form.confirmPassword.$dirty && form.confirmPassword.$invalid" class="padding-top padding-left assertive">
            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="form.confirmPassword.$error.required">
                some message
            </p>

            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="form.confirmPassword.$error.minlength">
                Sua confirmação de senha precisa ter no mínimo 5 caracteres.
            </p>

            <p class="help-block"
               ng-show="form.confirmPassword.$error.maxlength">
                Sua confirmação de senha deve ser menor que 50 caracteres.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-button">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-balanced">Criar conta</button>
        </small>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form is working correctly when there is no Ionic's tag, however, when I add a **ion-scroll** tag, either inside or outside form tag, the validation fails saying that password and confirm password are different. Should I use a specific Ionic tag with form? Which could be the tag I should use?

Comment: I've recently come across the same error. Have you found any fixes?

Comment: @tryingtolearn I've forgot about this question... The reason is because Ionic's elements uses it's own scope. I will answer this question later with more details

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'm struggling to find information on the topic so any work around you can suggest would be appreciated.

Comment: any insight you can offer?

Comment: @tryingtolearn I answered the question, perhaps it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because some ionic's components uses child scope, this kind of scope ["creates an 'isolate' scope that does not prototypically inherit."](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)
I solved my problem using the recommended best practice of use "." (dot) in my models. So I changed:

```
<input type="password" ng-model="confirmPassword" required>
```

to

```
<input type="password" ng-model="something.confirmPassword" required>
```